# Laravel No database selected

Tags: php, laravel

I just can't connect with my database in laravel, it's give me an error

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from users where email = )
>   .env  my database name is=empty

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=empty
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'empty'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you have a database that's called `empty`?

Comment: Yes created on phpmyadmin

Comment: ***Why on earth would you name your database `empty`?*** Didn't you got any name other than that? I feel `empty` word is reserved and should use some other name

Comment: yes I try alot of names as I faced this problem yesterday and I'm try with differant names

Comment: What's your project is all about? What's your project name?

Comment: My project about travel booking

Comment: name your database travel_booking, what's the matter? Please check the list of all reserved keywords which shouldn't be used as name of column, table, database names. [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-removed-in-current-series)

Comment: I just try different names because I faced this problem; my problem not the name the real problem there is no connection with the database

Comment: But your problem, your error in your question is clearly indicating that is the only problem you are facing.

Comment: yes It's the only problem

Comment: Can you post the query that is trying to be run?

Comment: Thank you all I'm created a new project now it's working well :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using reserved keywords at all to names of tables, columns, functions, stored_procedures, views, database.

Please find below link for reserved keywords in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-removed-in-current-series.

If still facing some problems. follow below commands.

1. composer update
2. composer dump-autoload
3. php artisan config:cache
4. php artisan view:clear
5. php artisan route:clear

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Although best practice is not using specific words, there is no technical problem by creating a table called `empty`. It's no problem and your answer not a solution for op's problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I'll try

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks for addressing a concern. But you should visit the link I mentioned in my answer. I feel my answer is sure addressing the problem what OP's asking for. So posted answer.

Comment: `empty` is not a reserved name prior to MySQL 8.0 I highly doubt this is the actual problem.

Comment: Judging op's configuration will be a ***DEBATE*** under the radar of ***DOUBT***.

Comment: Thank you all I'm created a new project now it's working well :)

Comment: @HimaHima what was the problem and did you rename it or with the same name?

Comment: I don't know how it solved I just restart server and new project by composer new database with new name it's worked well, as I try different names yesterday; but now It's work well. Thanks alot :)

Comment: The answer is in fact partially correct as no matter how many changes you bring to the env file, without clearing all the above, the changes wont reflect and you would be trying to fix a problem that has already been solved.